# Python PIL (Pillow) sometime generate garbage on transparent images

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When i'm create a image without color sometimes i get garbage (random color, point or lines)

```
image = Image.new("RGBA", (256, 256), None)

# draw a rectangle with rounded corners
image = draw_corner_box(image, radius=10)

# draw a rectangle with rounded corners and apply blur,
# paste image in the result and return
image = draw_shadow_box(image, radius=10)

image.save("image.png", "PNG")
```

#### Complete image

[image: Image generate with PIL]

#### Zoomed image

[image: Zoom Image generate with PIL]

Comment: The part of your script marked `# ...` is probably critical to answering this question. What happens if you draw nothing on `image`?

Comment: i'll try without draw nothing... yeah when draw nothing the problem is gone i'll check my draw method

Comment: i have a function draw a rectangle, when i draw a white rectangle is the problem, if a draw a black rectangle don't happens

Comment: At this point we need to reproduce the problem ourselves to be able to debug it.  So we need some example that we can run.